# "send to car" or how to send GPS to car SatNav

Tags: android, ios, api, gps

What I am looking at - is to send gps coordinates of multiple places I have on my device to "build-in car SatNav"(think BMW, M Benz, etx), so it can build a route between those coordinates and driver could use it on the move .

Question is simple - how to do that?

Searching forums and net gives no information on how to do that programmatically. I was not able to  find any API's.

However -  many car manufacturers provides this service and Google.maps user can do that from [browser](http://google-latlong.blogspot.co.uk/2010/07/google-maps-can-now-send-destinations.html)

Also - there is an [app](http://www.sendtocar-app.com/) available for both - iOS and Android, but how it is done - mystery that I didn't solve.

Will really appreciate any help/suggestion on this topic.

Thank you!

Comment: your question is not clear.Are you trying to track the car?

Comment: I am trying to send GPS coordinates that i have on my device - to car GPS; e.g Imagine I am traveling from A to B and I have coordinates for both of them. I want send A and B to car SatNav - so car can build up a route between A and B and navigate driver.